# Unable to connect Azure Linux VM from teraterm after disabling SELINUX option

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am using azure Linux centos 7.

For some purpose, I have disabled SELINUX option.

After that I am not able to connect VM from teraterm.

I am able to connect from azure portal serial console. I have enabled SELINUX from serial console but still I am not able to connect from teraterm,SFTP.

Error : connection refused.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start with the doc we have on troubleshooting SSH connections

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-ssh-connection

The connection refused error is generally a Firewall issue. So if the above link does not help then you might also try disabling the firewall using the serial console feature